# Horizontal Rows as Vertical Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, native-sql

I have this requirement where I need to present horizontal rows as vertical columns in SQL Server native query.

For example, my select query returns 100 records for the select query using inner join.

```sql
select  XX, XX etc  FROM TAB1 con inner join TAB2 reg on con.id = reg.reference_id WHERE con.is_active=1 and
            con.approval_status=3 order by XXX
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now I want my query returning 1 records for 10 records where dynamic columns name should be created based on the business_ids for example 670_h_current, 671_h_current etc for all those 10 records. The result should be returned as a single query with 10 dynamic columns each represents a row value for business id and hcurrent.

I tried to use the Pivot table, but it does not seem working.Is there a way to manipulate the SQLs to return the required number of records. I am doing it at the moment in java but fetching all the records, then transforming. However, pagnation is an issue and my interface is slower as it picks a lot of records. I wanted the select query fetches a reduced view of records.

Any idea? Any help much appreciated

Current Select output

```sql
ID          DEP LEG MAS     EXE  DES        P1  BUS_ID  ATTE
==================================================================
COI_AP002   215 216 4071    758 clients.    NULL    673 1
COI_AP002   215 216 4071    758 clients.    NULL    672 0

Expected Output

ID          DEP LEG MAS     EXE  DES    P1    ATTE_673  ATTE_672
==========================================================================
COI_AP002   215 216 4071    758 clients. NULL   1          0
```

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you. Provide sample data in a consumable format, preferably DDL and DML statements, and don't forget to include your expected results **and** your attempt(s).

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. Then, you need to do a little work, to learn the concept, and to get it to do exactly what you want it to do.

```
--Drop Table dbo.Lateral
CREATE TABLE dbo.Lateral
( Id  VARCHAR(100),
  Dep int,
  Des VARCHAR(100),
  Bus_ID int,
  Atte int)

--Delete from Account

INSERT INTO dbo.Lateral
  (Id, Dep, Des, Bus_ID, Atte)
VALUES
  ('COI_AP002','215','clients',673,1)
INSERT INTO dbo.Lateral
  (Id, Dep, Des, Bus_ID, Atte)
VALUES
 ('COI_AP002','215','clients',672,0)

Select *
From Lateral
```

[image]

```
select 
x.ID,
sum(case when t.bus_id = '673' then 1 end) atte_673,
sum(case when t.bus_id =' 672' then 0 end) atte_672
from lateral t
cross apply (values 
('COI_AP002' , t.bus_ID)
) as x(ID, val)
group by x.ID
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for the reply. This is what I was looking for. Have been working on another high priority stuff, will be trying to implement this later today. Will comeback to you in case of further questions. Thanks a lot for the reply, much appreciated

Comment: Sounds good. Please mark the answer as useful if it helps you. Thanks.